# I'm thirsty. So, what's the difference?

Tags: wordplay

> I'm a place to land, but not be constrained.
>
> I'm always there to cheer you on, but then I can't eat.
>
> I'm one who uses a modem, but then can't even list files.
>
> I can hold volumes, but I keep away from ladies' fingers.
>
> When all else fails I decide, but only when the night air is silent.
>
> And if you see me from behind, you'll know I'm fit to be a king.

**What's this all about?**

*Hint*

> Each line should be solved independently, and the answers to each line are related.  The title tells you how to solve each line except the last one, which involves a different type of wordplay.

*Hint* =

> I'm a Japanese religion, but don't care about the initial SE site's initials.

Comment: Possible clue: Okra is sometimes referred to as "ladies fingers"

Comment: @John That was just obscure enough to possibly make sense but possibly not make sense.

Comment: @DanRussell, Yeah, I realize that.  Let me keep looking at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm thirsty. What's the difference?

> You can find a type of beer by subtracting the second half of the sentence from the first.

I'm a place to land, but not be constrained.

> "place to land" -> *helipad* 
>  "constrained" -> *held* 
>  HELIPAD - HELD = **IPA**

I'm always there to cheer you on, but then I can't eat.

> "cheer you on" -> *supporter* 
>  "eat" -> *sup* (synonym of 'eat') 
>  SUPPORTER - SUP = **PORTER**

I'm one who uses a modem, but then can't even list files.

> "one who uses a modem" -> *dialer* (think dial-up modem)
>  "list files" -> *dir* (Windows shell command to list files) 
> DIALER - DIR = **ALE**

I can hold volumes, but I keep away from ladies' fingers.

> "hold volumes" -> *bookrack* (volumes = books) 
>  "ladies' fingers" -> *okra* (nickname; thanks to @Areeb) 
> BOOKRACK - OKRA = **BOCK**

When all else fails I decide, but only when the night air is silent.

> "when all else fails, I decide" -> *shootout* (final 'decider' of tied soccer/hockey games) 
>  "night air is silent" -> *hoo* (sound of an owl; a night without a 'hoo' is silent) 
>  SHOOTOUT - HOO = **STOUT**

And if you see me from behind, you'll know I'm fit to be a king.

> Different scheme for this one: 
> REGAL backwards = **LAGER**

Comment: 2nd hint: SHINTO-SO=HINT.

Comment: Nicely done. I'd buy you one if I could!

Comment: second line - but then I can't eat = SUP..could someone explain?

Comment: I'm adding clarifications in the solution; "sup" is a synonym of "eat"

Answer (score 1):

I've got something. It fits with half of the riddle, but I'm missing three lines...

You're a

> Mouth

I'm a place to land, but not be constrained.

> Food *lands* there, but does not stay there forever because it is swallowed right after.

I'm always there to cheer you on, but then I can't eat.

> To cheer on someone you need to speak and you can't eat while speaking

I'm one who uses a modem, but then can't even list files.

??

I can hold volumes, but I keep away from ladies' fingers.

> There's a bit of space (volume) inside the mouth. When you kiss a lady's hand  your mouth shouldn't touch her fingers.

When all else fails I decide, but only when the night air is silent.

??

And if you see me from behind, you'll know I'm fit to be a king.

??

I'll think about this for a little longer, but it's quite late and I need to sleep.

EDIT:

> For some reason a part of me thinks that it may have something to do with chess... Talking about eating, files (columns of a chessboard), king and maybe queen (aria (= air) of the night queen from Mozart's Magic Flute)

Comment: Good effort, but not what I'm after. Needs a bit more wordplay with the clues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a place to land, but not be constrained.

> A landing* page.

I'm always there to cheer you on, but then I can't eat.

I'm one who uses a modem, but then can't even list files.

> A fax* page.

I can hold volumes, but I keep away from ladies' fingers.

> A page file*.

When all else fails I decide, but only when the night air is silent.

And if you see me from behind, you'll know I'm fit to be a king.

> Something to do with a king's* page(page boy)?

What's this all about?

> Pages is my guess right now, but it's reaching.

Comment: Good effort, but you'll need to actually modify some of the clued words to find the solution.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "clued words"?

Comment: night air = knight heir? just a thought